# How to get URL address and pass it to a script as a parameter / variable?

Tags: variables, url

I am trying to get url address by windown.location.href and pass it as a value to a tracking script.

the code I wrote looks like this :

`function (){
var currentLocation = window.location.href;
(new Image).src = 'http://www.tester-iwan.com?/siteid='+ currentLocation +'&gc=12';
})();`

however it does not work.

So basically what I need is to get whole URL address as a variable and pass it to "siteid" parameter.

I will be thankful for an assistance.

Thank you in advance,
Michał

Answer (score 0):

I have found a mistake in my code and found a solution to this. 
the code that catches URL and passes it to relevant script should looks like :

```
var currentLocation = window.location.href;
(function(){
(new Image()).src='http://www.tester-iwan.com?/siteid='+ currentLocation +'&gc=12';
})();
```

Thanks